# not show decimals in PHP Value?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a web made in laravel, livewire and I need to hide decimals in variable: 'valor' => $countPoblacion->poblacion]
since it is currently showing decimals in all values.

```
class ConteoPoblacion extends Conteo
{
    protected function cargarDatos($args = null)
    {
        if ($this->tieneArgumento('idMunicipio', $args))
        {
            $countPoblacion = Distrito::select(
                DB::raw('SUM(poblacion) as poblacion'),
                DB::raw('SUM(km2) as km2'),
            )
            ->where('id', '=', $args['idMunicipio'])
            ->first();

            return [
                ['nombre' => 'poblacion', 'valor' => $countPoblacion->poblacion],
                ['nombre' => 'densidad (hab/km2)', 'valor' => $countPoblacion->poblacion / $countPoblacion->km2],
                ['nombre' => 'superficie en km2', 'valor' => $countPoblacion->km2],
            ];
        } else if ($this->tieneArgumento('idSeccion', $args))
        {
            $countPoblacion = Distrito::select(
                DB::raw('SUM(poblacion) as poblacion'),
                DB::raw('SUM(km2) as km2'),
            )
            ->where('seccion_id', '=', $args['idSeccion'])
            ->first();

            return [
                ['nombre' => 'poblacion', 'valor' => $countPoblacion->poblacion],
                ['nombre' => 'densidad (hab/km2)', 'valor' => $countPoblacion->poblacion / $countPoblacion->km2],
                ['nombre' => 'superficie en km2', 'valor' => $countPoblacion->km2],
            ];
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try rounding the numbers? Using any of these functions

`round()`

`floor()`

or

`ceil()`

Comment: Could you show me how I should put it in my code?